# Django Multiselectfield allows to add any value which is not in choice list from shell, How to prevent that?

Tags: django

```
 DEPARTMENT_CHOICE = (
    ('BCT','Department Of Electronics and Computer Engineering'),
    ('BEL','Deparment Of Electrical Engineering'),
    ('BCE','Deparment Of Civil Engineering'),
    ('SHE','Deparment Of Science and Humanities'),
    ('BME','Deparment Of Mechanical Engineering'),
    )
department = models.CharField (max_length =10 ,choices = DEPARTMENT_CHOICE,blank=True,verbose_name="Department")
```

But if we add eg ZZZ in department, it will be added in database but I want to prevent that. How can I do it to prevent add items which are not in choice tuple?

Comment: You call `.clean()` *before* `.save()` on your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Django ORM does *not* calls the validators to check if the values make sense. `ModelForm`s call the [appropriate cleaning and validation [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation).

You can however call [**`.full_clean()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) on the model object before saving it. This will raise an error in case the object contains invalid data. For example:

```
>>> m = Model(department='ZZZ')
>>> m.full_clean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/some/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1166, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'department': ["Value 'ZZZ' is not a valid choice."]}
```

So this will raise a `ValidationError` in case the model object does not satisfies the constraints that are not enforced at database level.

Note that ORM calls still circumvent that: for example `Model.objects.create(department='ZZZ')` will ignore validation, as well as bulk updates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The choices can only restrict what can be entered through a Django form. When you manually instantiate your object you can insert any value...

I guess the trick is to not allow the user to add any instance manually.